# Creating parcels of equal areas in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I want split a polygon of approximately 100ha (land) into parcels of 500m2 and I'm   lost.

Is there a tool, extension, or code that you can share with me to do it using QGIS?

Comment: Unfortunately, splitting an arbitrary polygon into even pieces is *not* a trivial task. There are potential simplifications, but you have not described the task in such a way that we could tell if they apply. You've also doubled the breadth of the problem by specifying two different software platforms. Please [Edit] the question to provide more information on your exact task, including a picture of the parcel you're trying to split with a sketch of your goal, and details about how you tried to solve the problem. In order to limit scope, you'll need to choose either ArcGIS or QGIS.

Comment: It's gotten and I'm sorry if I didn't respect the rules.

Comment: Difficulty depends on the shape of the polygon (is it convex?) and whether you have any fixed or optimisable restrictions on the shape of the output parcels or whether they even have to be contiguous.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your polygon? I think the level of difficulty of this task will depend on the shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fully automated solution would be much more complicated, and would require more information than you've provided. However, the **Split Features on Steroids plugin** can assist you in doing this task manually.

> **Split features showing areas on each side allowing the edition of the cutting line vertices**
>
> Split one or more polygon/multipolygon features showing the resulting
>   areas on each side of the cutting line. Adjust the vertices of the
>   cutting line before splitting.

### Split a polygon into parcels of a desired size with the Split Features on Steroids plugin

1. Install the plugin from the plugin manager.
2. *Select* the feature you want to split (the layer must be in editing mode).
3. Click the 'Split Feature on Steroids' button on the toolbar.

[image]

4. Draw a split line across your polygon but *don't* right click to finish splitting. The plugin automatically calculates and displays the area of each piece.

[image]

4. Use the other tools to adjust the split line.
5. When you're satisfied, right click to finish the split.

Comment: Thank you very much! I finally succeeded using the extension "Split Features on Steroids".